# spark using only one core on parallelism task

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, apache-spark, cpu

So i have this code:

```
conf = SparkConf().setAll((
    ("spark.python.profile", "true" if args.profile else "false"),
    ("spark.task.maxFailures", "20"),
    ("spark.driver.cores", "4"),
    ("spark.executor.cores", "4"),
    ("spark.shuffle.service.enabled", "true"),
    ("spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled", "true"),
))

# TODO could this be set somewhere in cosr-ops instead?
executor_environment = {}
if config["ENV"] == "prod":
    executor_environment = {
        "PYTHONPATH": "/cosr/back",
        "PYSPARK_PYTHON": "/cosr/back/venv/bin/python",
        "LD_LIBRARY_PATH": "/usr/local/lib"
    }

sc = SparkContext(appName="Common Search Index", conf=conf, environment=executor_environment)

# First, generate a list of all WARC files
warc_filenames = list_warc_filenames()

# Then split their indexing in Spark workers
warc_records = sc.parallelize(warc_filenames, 4).flatMap(iter_records)
```

While it lounches all the spark stuff it uses all the cores.

But when it starts to do the task( indexing ), then it only uses 1 core on 100%.

How to make one spark task use all of the cores ?

Comment: This won't do anything...it doesn't call an action

Comment: It does, itter_records contains the work.

Comment: When its called it starts to index warc bodys to ES clusters.

Comment: It's impossible to help without at least the code from iter_records. We are not fortune tellers unfortunately.

Comment: Nooo, flatMap is not an action. I don't care what's in iter_records...you need to call an action to trigger the DAG

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was in the python itself not using all cores. I implemented multi-threading.

Thanks for all who helped.